# Emulate number pad with Lenovo x220 Laptop?

Tags: keyboard, blender

I need a number pad with Lenovo x220 laptop and I lack external kbd, for using Blender more on the point 3.10 [here](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2010/08/31/blender-interface-and-navigation/) and this discussion [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4184634#4184634). The keyboard with X220 is similar to this one where the middle keys have numbers like a number -pad.

[image]

How can I get a number pad working so that they do the typical number-pad-functions in Blender? Look the above number row is not programmed to work like the number pad, I need the real number pad function keys. How?

(Btw I run Ubuntu, W and other OSs so I would like to find some OS -independent solution.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>ScrLk</kbd> will turn toggle NumLock, which will activate the numeric keypad in the middle of the keyboard.

Comment: where is ScrLk -key?

Comment: It's right there, towards the top-right.

Comment: Nice, thanks found it, and it works with Blender! +1 :)

Comment: it would be much better if "fn +  the desired key" would work, instead always have to have 4 combinations pressed to essentially have numpad key entered. Stupid laptop unusable blender